# $(window).innerHeight() - "height of certain div by id"

Tags: javascript, dynamic

sorry, I really am not a javascript-expert. Maybe someone can help me achieve this. Ich have a full-height div, which I define with this code

```
    $(function(){
      $('#foxfix-<?php echo $i ?>').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() - 40 });
      $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#foxfix-<?php echo $i ?>').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() - 40 });
      });
    });
```

The "40px" give space to of a fixed-bottom div.

My problem is: the fixed bottom div (id="example") has a dynamic height because of the entered text.

**How can I get the height of the div (id="example") and combine it with my code on the top to get something like $(window).innerHeight() - "height of div (id="example")"?**

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but to take the height of an element just use this method: `$('#example').offsetHeight`

Comment: Yes, but I need to subtract that from the inner height to get height for the div #forfix. This does not make any sense, does it: 

$('#foxfix-<?php echo $i ?>').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() - $('#example').offsetHeight });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try getting height of div with .height() https://api.jquery.com/height/ and then set this height to window.innerHeight(**value**) https://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/#innerHeight2

```
let div_height = $('#example').height()
$(window).innerHeight(div_height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Final code

```
    $(function(){

    var height = $(window).innerHeight();
    var k = $('#example-<?php echo $i ?>').height();


      $('#foxfix-<?php echo $i ?>').css({ height: height - k });
      $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#foxfix-<?php echo $i ?>').css({ height: height - k });
      });
    });
```